# Way to nest multiple voice triggers when launching an app with GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to nest voice triggers when launching an app on Google Glass using the GDK? For example instead of just saying "ok, glass" -> "What's its power level?" I'd like to have the app present an option. For example "ok, glass" -> "What's its power level?" -> "Over 9000" OR "Under 9000".  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have multiple activities/services installed on Glass that have the same voice trigger intent filter, all of their names (based on the `android:label` attribute of the `<activity>` or `<service>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`) will appear in a disambiguation "submenu" when you speak that voice trigger.

For example (assume that `res/xml/play_a_game_trigger.xml` represents a voice trigger for the string *"play a game"*):

```
<activity android:label="Tennis">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/play_a_game_trigger" />
</activity>
<activity android:label="Bowling">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/play_a_game_trigger" />
</activity>
```

would give you a voice menu flow that looks like

```
ok glass → play a game → Tennis
                         Bowling
```

Do note, however, that this menu would also include activities/services from *other* APKs that use the same voice trigger as well.

You can find more details at the [Voice Input](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice) page of the GDK documentation.

Comment: Shouldn't `android:name="Bowling"` be `android:label="Bowling"`? I'm sure it falls back to activity name but label should be the appropriate attribute.

Comment: Oops, yes, you're correct, thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: When I use this approach the top-level app item ("Play a game") in the "ok glass" tap menu does not display an icon.  However, once I tap the "Play a game" item, the submenu items  ("Tennis", "Bowling") have icons.  Anyone have a solution to get an app-wide icon in the menu?

Comment: @ptc I think the reason for this is because Google thinks your app's voice trigger has a label clash with another app, so the top-level menu does not show the icon of any app, then the submenu items show the app's icon.

Comment: I believe this behavior no longer works under XE17.1. Deploying a GDK app with this, the "Home" menu crashes when tapped using the touchpad (it doesn't load the app menu). The "OK Glass" voice command still works.

Comment: @TonyAllevato What if both of these "bowling" and "Tennis" belong to the same activity ? Android doesn't allow us to declare the activity name twice in the manifest  ?

Comment: You should be able to use an <activity-alias> to achieve this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is using an **input** tag inside the trigger

```
<trigger keyword="@string/start_app" >

    <input prompt="@string/promt_text" />

</trigger>
```

This prompts an input and waits for more audio speech.

Then in your activity you can capture this text with:

```
ArrayList<String> text = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```